# Different style in Chrome and IE11

Tags: html, css

I got really annoying problem. Chrome and IE interprets stylesheet differently. Sometimes difference is like `5-10px` (not a problem) but sometimes `100-200px`.

The thing is that I use `z-index` and `position:relative` does this have an impact?

I've tried everything: different stylesheet for IE using get navigator (or something like that, don't remember now), IE-only comments. nothing helped.

Is there any way to fix this problem? I am creating a game, so it would be nice if it worked on every browser

Comment: The majority of the time it'll be due to different browser default padding/margin for certain elements. Are you using a CSS reset? Do you have an example you could isolate & post of one of these cases?

Comment: Are you using some king of "reset" CSS. You could try with Normalize.css: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently and got the tip of using "overflow: hidden" on objects that could cause overflow. IE was kinder in this regard, letting objects flow even when here were "collisions", but I guess Chrome was more correct.

It fixed issues for me, so it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Because all the browsers have their own way of implementation of CSS, it is always good to add `default css` that will override their existing nature and bring everything at same level. Add reset.css at the top

reset.css

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```